# iMessage log in Problem

Tags: apple-id, messages, facetime

This is the error I am getting at the moment when I try to log into iMessage. The same error occured when using FaceTime. I can use my appleID for the Appstore. 
Do you know what I can do about this?

[image: error message]

Comment: It could be that Apple's servers are bogged down because of the WWDC and release of new OS's to developers. I'm not seeing any system outages, though. I would try again later. https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Answer (score 1):

This is a commmon problem with Hackintosh'ed computers. Is the computer you are using with OSX genuine?

Wether it is a real Mac device or not, the steps to fix this should be very similar. [Here](http://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/how-to-fix-imessage.110471/) is a **very** long thread describing each step to fix this in great detail.

To start off, I would make sure that your Apple ID is verified. You can check the 'Verified' status of your AppleID by logging into [AppleID's online management](https://appleid.apple.com/).

Comment: thank you for the reply. The Hardware is real mac and the software as well, as far as I know. I have turned off system integrety protection as the only modification to the normal OS X. Where can I find the verified status? I logged in but cant find it.